# Is it possible to make a pile of elements without using z-index?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a pile of divs using z-index. In order to do so I need to use **position:absolute;** ... but the problem is that the **width:100%;** on each element doesn't work well because it **overlaps the width of the parent element**

I have here like ...

```
//I'm using bootstrap css row-fluid to contain the dev
<div class="row-fluid" style="position: relative;">
   <div id="elem1" style="width:100%; z-index:4; position: absolute;" ></div>
   <div id="elem2" style="width:100%; z-index:3; position: absolute;" ></div>
   <div id="elem3" style="width:100%; z-index:2; position: absolute;" ></div>
   <div id="elem4" style="width:100%; z-index:1; position: absolute;" ></div>
</div>
```

The elements inside the parent will overlap the parent's width. If anyone here has better idea how this mess be solved I would really appreciate it.. thank you

Comment: This question is unclear. Please be more specific.

Comment: Any other ways to make a pile of elements?.. or how would I make 100% WIDTH with POSITION: ABSOLUTE...? that wouldn't overlap its parent WIDTH

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` works only with positioned elements.

So position absolute is not compulsory.

You can use z-index with

- `position:absolute`
- `position:relative`
- `position:fixed`

Comment: Any other ways to make a pile of elements?.. or how would I make 100% WIDTH with POSITION: ABSOLUTE...? that wouldn't overlap its parent WIDTH

Comment: Post a demo of your code. I've only answer at your first question

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```css
#elem1{
  background: #000;
}
#elem2{
  background: #e4ff00;
}
#elem3{
  background: #ffbc00;
}
#elem4{
  background: #ff8d00;
}
div{
  height: 30px;
  top:0;
}
.relative-holder{
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid" style="position: relative;">
   <div id="elem1" style="width:100%; z-index:4; position: absolute;" >
     <div class="relative-holder" style="position:relative;">
     <div id="elem2" style="width:100%; z-index:3; position: absolute;" >
       <div class="relative-holder"  style="position:relative" >
         
     <div id="elem3" style="width:100%; z-index:2; position: absolute;" >
       <div  class="relative-holder"  style="position:relative" >
       
     <div id="elem4" style="width:100%; z-index:1; position: absolute;" ></div>
       </div>
     </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.. I just used **left:0 right:0** to expand the divs within parent div without overlapping parent's width.. thanks for the comments and answer :-)